# Cannot find '$searchText' in scope

Tags: swiftui

swift ui で

.searchable(text: $searchText)

を使おうとすると

Cannot find '$searchText' in scope

というアラートが出ます。

.searchableを置いているstructの中に

@State private var searchtext = [""]

を置いています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

textは`[String]`ではなく、`String`を必要としています。
おそらく変数を宣言する場所が間違えているため、`searchText`が見つかっていません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。お察しのとおりでした。ですが、""にしたあともでます。

Comment: 大丈夫でした。searchtextにしていました。すみません。